# How to include special characters in the 'when' module?

Tags: linux, ansible, redhat

The variable *error_code* below contains this string:

> *"failed": true*

How can I use this string as the trigger for the 'when module? I am not sure how to escape these special characters so the playbook interprets them correctly. Here's what I have tried but it is not working:

```
  - name: copying index
    copy: 
      src: /tmp/index.html
      dest: /var/www/html/
    notify: reloadone
    register: error_code
  - name: verify content
    fail:
      msg: There has been an error with the index file
    when: " \"failed\"\: true in error_code"
  handlers:
  - name: reloadone
    systemd:
      state: restarted
      name: httpd
```

Comment: `when: '"\"failed\": true" in error_code'`? `variable error_code below contains this string:` vs `copy: register: error_code` That's odd, are you sure it _contains_ that string? Do you want just `when: error_code.failed`???

Comment: the variable 'error_code' registers the output from the copy task. This output contains an error which is pretty long including the following string         "failed": true,    . How can i insert this into the 'when' module here?

Comment: Yes, but _not in the form of a string_. Just `when: error_code.failed`. `register` sets a data structure, with keys and values. What you are seeing is JSON _representation_ of the data-structure. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#common-return-values and https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#return-values . Also, it's odd, because when `copy` fails, the execution should stop... You shouldn't be able to execute anything after it.

Comment: Ok thats definitely a cleaner solution!, thank you.  is the second part of "error_code.failed" just a text string I will need to change dependent on the output or will this work for any failed task? also this is just part of a playbook I have   ignore_errors: yes in the header thats why execution continues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the string into the [single-guotes](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#732-single-quoted-style), e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    error_code: '"failed": true'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: error_code
    - name: verify content
      fail:
        msg: There has been an error with the index file
      when: error_code == result
      vars:
        result: '"failed": true'
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  error_code: '"failed": true'

TASK [verify content] *********************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: There has been an error with the index file
```

---

The next option is to convert the string to a dictionary and test the Boolean value of the attribute *failed*, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    error_code: '"failed": true'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: error_code|from_yaml
    - name: verify content
      fail:
        msg: There has been an error with the index file
      when: result.failed
      vars:
        result: "{{ error_code|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  error_code|from_yaml:
    failed: true

TASK [verify content] *******************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: There has been an error with the index file
```

---

If the code doesn't fail

```yaml
    error_code: '"failed": false'
```

the condition will be skipped

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  error_code|from_yaml:
    failed: false

TASK [verify content] ********************************************
skipping: [localhost]
```